# What should I use with this problem about SQL

Tags: sql

Suppose that you will run an email marketing campaign in Japan for which you will need the names and email addresses. Create a query to display the data

what query or function will i use

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: please provide some sample data and desired output and specify DB you use

Comment: First, this looks like "Please do my homework."; we expect people to at least attempt to answer the question themselves. Second, there's no data, so we cannot help anyway.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

Although your question is quite vague but let me try.

It might look like,

```
SELECT NAME, EMAIL FROM DESIRED_TABLE WHERE COUNTRY='JAPAN';
```

Condition can be applied accordingly.